# How to POST iterable data from tables

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I have a table with some date in it:

```
        <tr class="unit-table'"> 
          <td><input type="text" name="" id="item"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" id="price"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" id="qty"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" id="disc"></td>
        </tr>
```

User can add new rows to this table. I'm using Fetch API to post this data. The response from API am trying to post is looks like this

```
 "computer_and_infrastructure": [
            {
                "item": "Computer Support",
                "unit_price": 30,
                "qty": 5,
                "discount": 0
            }
        ]
```

My question is how can I loop through all table data and add it to my request?

Comment: Rather than looping over the table yourself to try and extract all the field values, you should be giving the input fields proper names to begin with (that match those that you need to send as parameter names to the API), and then create a `FormData` instance by passing your form element to the constructor. It will create the whole form submission data set for you.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I still have some issues with using FormData. When I'm tying to send this instance, I see only field named, but values are empty. Could you please give me a hand in this?

Comment: You need to show the actual code you have a problem with.

Comment: Well, I dealt with that by myself:)
I used Object.fromEntries(formData) to pass all the values
Thank you for your help again!